# raster to polygon problems in R

Tags: r, polygon, raster

I have a raster layer image and want to convert it to polygons shapefile! My problem is when I convert the raster with `rasterToPolygons` function in `R` ( and `dissolve= TRUE`) then the number of polygons that I see in the shapefile doeasnt match with infos written from the result! 
for example, here in the shapefile I see 11 polygons but in the infos it tells me number of features are 9;

```
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 9 
extent      : 634230, 634680, 5367740, 5368020  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 1
names       : allData_03_04_03_scl_FILT_sr5_rr0o1_SEGM_f0o5_ms20_LSMS_segm 
min values  :                                                            1 
max values  :                                                           11
```

Any suggestion how I can correct it and also count all the polygons?

Comment: If you use `dissolve = TRUE`, polygons with the same value will be merged to one feature. So you might "see" 11 polygons, which might be just 9 features

Comment: @Val so is there any solution? my raster layer it does have 11 values and I expected that I will also have 11 features not 9!

Comment: Try using `dissolve=FALSE`

Comment: I tried but then it counts every cell as a polygon!!!!

Comment: what makes you think btw that there are 11 polygons? In your post i only see that the _maximum_ value is 11. Maybe you could be a bit more specific on how your data looks like and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: ah ok, it may be confusing! so I just clustered my raster values and then I put these values back to raster( I changed the cells values which are in one cluster to same value) and then at the end I want that each value of raster will be one polygon! thats improtant for me, becuase I wanna label each polygon then and if they are not 11 then  my labeling doesnt work!

Comment: I suspect that you don't have all 11 values occurring in your raster, maybe something went wrong with overwriting the values. Maybe you can update your question with your workflow

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Polygon2 <- sp::disaggregate(Polygon)
```